# Airflow DAG can't find local file to upload on s3

Tags: python, docker, amazon-s3, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have created a DAG to upload a local file into a personal S3 Bucket. However, when accessing http://localhost:9099/home I get the following error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\plata\OneDrive\Υπολογιστής\projects backups\airflow-sqlserver\dags\pricedata.xlsx'

[Ariflow error - broken dag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZY7S.png)

I have a Windows PC and I am running airflow on a docker container.

Here is the DAG's code:

```
# airflow related
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
# other packages
from datetime import datetime
import boto3

with DAG(
    dag_id='file_to_s3',
    start_date=datetime(2022, 12, 5),
    catchup=False,
) as dag:
    pass


def file_to_s3():
    #Creating Session With Boto3.
    session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id='my_access_key_id',
    aws_secret_access_key='my_secret_access_key'
    )

    #Creating S3 Resource From the Session.
    s3 = session.resource('s3')

    result = s3.Bucket('flight-data-test-bucket').upload_file(r'C:\Users\plata\OneDrive\Υπολογιστής\projects backups\airflow-sqlserver\dags\pricedata.xlsx', 'pricedata.xlsx')

    return (result)


with DAG(
    dag_id='file_to_s3',
    start_date=datetime(2022, 12, 5),
    catchup=False
) as dag:
    # Upload the file
    task_file_to_s3 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='file_to_s3',
        python_callable=file_to_s3()
    )
```

I can't understand why that happens since I have already stored my local file into my "dags" folder:

[pricedata.xlsx location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsyv3.png)

And my "dags" folder is already mounted in the *docker-compose.yml* file which can be seen below:

```
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    # For backward compatibility, with Airflow <2.3
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ./data:/opt/airflow/data
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
```

Any ideas? Could this problem caused by the fact I am running Airflow on Windows through Docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file system of your docker containers are not shared with windows by default.

You can mount a drive so that you can persist files and share them between your windows and your docker:

https://www.docker.com/blog/file-sharing-with-docker-desktop/

note that in your docker, you will need the file path seen "in your docker container"

with your docker compose, it looks like your xslx files is mounted here:
`./dags:/opt/airflow/dags`

So I assume, that in your dag code, you could try:

`result = s3.Bucket('flight-data-test-bucket').upload_file(r'/opt/airflow/dags/pricedata.xlsx', 'pricedata.xlsx')`

It might be a good idea to mount an additional drive with your project data outside of the DAG folder.

Comment: Indeed the file could be found after changing the path to the following 

'result = s3.Bucket('flight-data-test-bucket').upload_file('/opt/airflow/dags/pricedata.xlsx', 'pricedata.xlsx')'

.I had also to remove the '()' from my last line making it "python_callable=file_to_s3"

Now the DAG is not broken anymore. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I edited the answer to add the '/' in the file path following @panos response

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it after changing the path to: `result = s3.Bucket('flight-data-test-bucket').upload_file('/opt/airflow/dags/pricedata.xlsx', 'pricedata.xlsx')`

I had to also fix the `python_callable=file_to_s3()` to `python_callable=file_to_s3`